# javascript or php function to add something to the beginning and end of text

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been looking for something that would add `<td>` to the beginning of text and then `</td>` at the end of text

Can anybody help with this or point me some where I can find out how to do it

For example, if a user puts text like this

```
item    2,119   1,403   233.090 1,741,670   110 821
```

I need the page to automatically add a `<td>` to the beginning and end of the text like this

```
<td>item</td><td>2,119</td><td>1,403</td><td>233.090</td><td>1,741,670</td><td>110</td><td>821</td>
```

Edit:-

now I have another problem I forgot about if there is more than one line of text that a user has put and there want it to come up in a list.

```
        Names   1   2   3   4   5
ItemA   2,119   1,403   233.090 1,741,670   110 821
ItemB   957 370 250,734 757,278 262 791
itemC   16  13  0   18,811  0   1,175
ItemD   630 281 347,956 1,260,205   552 2,000
```

So i need it to do this

```
<tr><td>ItemA</td>  <td>2,119</td>  <td>1,403</td>  <td>233.090</td>    <td>1,741,670</td>  <td>110 821</td></tr>
<tr><td>ItemB</td>  <td>957 <td>370 <td>250,734 <td>757,278</td>    <td>262 <td>791</td></tr>
<tr><td>itemC</td>  <td>16</td> <td>13</td> <td>0</td>  <td>18,811</td> <td>0   <td>1,175</td></tr>
<tr><td>ItemD</td>  <td>630</td>    <td>281</td>    <td>347,956</td>    <td>1,260,205</td>  <td>552 2,000</td></tr>
```

So at the  beginning of every line and at the end of every line I need a `<tr>` and `</tr>` so on my web page it comes up in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PHP solution. Uses `explode()` on spaces, `array_filter()` removes empty values from array, then `implode()` again:

```
<?php
$vals   =   "item    2,119   1,403   233.090 1,741,670   110 821";
echo '<td>'.implode("</td><td>",array_filter(explode(" ",$vals))).'</td>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you :) just what I needed

Comment: how does that solution handle multiple spaces and leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: @JaromandaX It will filter out spaces when it explodes and uses `array_filter()`

Comment: ahh, array_filter - didn't see that :p

Comment: The only problem is if i want 2 lines of 'item    2,119   1,403   233.090 1,741,670   110 821' and say 'item2    2,119   1,403   233.090 1,741,670   110 821' it will just be on the same line  I have tried fix it by putting <tr> next to <td> but can't get it to work any ideas? @Rasclatt

Comment: @James99g Sorry, I missed your comment. Can you edit your question with what you are faced with now so I can see it? Just add a new part after what you have.

Comment: Use file() then loop with for()

Comment: After and before each row do the <tr></tr>

Comment: Thanks but could you edit you answer as i dont know where to put the file() or for() in the code am still new at php @Rasclatt

Comment: Hey man, it's not really in the spirit of things when people answer your question that you accept, later to unaccept because the afterthought to your original question isn't answered to your satisfaction. No one is going to want to help you when you that kind of thing.

Comment: Oh sorry must of passed it when chrome was freezing on me I will fix it right now.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (in javascript)

```
output = '<td>' + input.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '</td><td>') + '</td>';
```

the trim() is there to remove leading/trailing spaces in the input, just to be sure

Comment: Thanks but I will be going with the PHP solution as when I was testing it was the best way to stop users from deleting the code

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=$("<td></td>");
result.html( inputString.split(" ").join("</td><td>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can split your string or user input by space(seperator)**

**PHP** function take your string and seperator charcter like space ' '

```
<?php
    function splitStr($str, $seperator) {
        $ret = "";
        $strArr = explode($seperator, $str);
        for($i=0; $i<count($strArr); ++$i) {
            $ret .= '<td>' . $strArr[$i] . '</td>';
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    // invoke splitStr
    echo splitStr('item    2,119   1,403   233.090 1,741,670   110 821',' ');
?>
```

**JavaScript** function same php above function

```
function splitStr(str, seperator) {
    var ret = '';
    var strArr = str.split(seperator);
    for(var i=0; i<strArr.length; ++i) {
        ret += '<td>' + strArr[i] +. '</td>';
    }
        return ret;
}
alert(splitStr('item    2,119   1,403   233.090 1,741,670   110 821',' '));
```